# How can I get the key of the object

Tags: javascript

I have a big object, and I need to get the parent object, for example: I need to get the name of key `(obj12)` but I got only the value of obj12, so how can I get the name of key`(obj12)` of the value `{login: 'example', password: 'example'}?`

```
const obj = {
    obj1: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj2: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj3: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj4: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj5: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj6: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj7: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj8: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj9: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj10: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj11: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj12: {login: 'example', password: 'example'},
    obj13: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj14: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj15: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj16: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'}
}
```

Comment: Isn't `obj12` the name of the key?

Comment: What if you had `{login: 'hello', password: 'world'}`? Which is then the desired result? And do you really have *that* object, or do you have a copy of it?

Comment: I just have only values of the obj12 like {login: 'example', password: 'example'} and how can I get the key if I have only value of key

Comment: Do you want to get key(obj12) from value {login: 'example', password: 'example}?

Comment: Thomas Jiang, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can solve i guess

```js
const objects = {
    obj1: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj2: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj3: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj4: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj5: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj6: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj7: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj8: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj9: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj10: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj11: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj12: {login: 'example', password: 'example'},
    obj13: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj14: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj15: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'},
    obj16: {login: 'hello', password: 'world'}
}

keys = Object.keys(objects)

for (const key of keys){
  if(objects[key]['login'] == 'example')
     console.log(key)
}
```